# Basic AC circuit analysis with wattmeter data

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, basic

I am having trouble dealing with this exercise. The data given is: **UG=90V**, **ω=190rad/s**, **V1=0V**, **V2=35V**, **W=900W** **Power factor=1.**

Being the power factor equal to 1, I can get the current intensity using the active power formula P=UG⋅I⋅cosφ, as the total intensity is in phase with the voltage. I=10A

However, I don't know how to proceed from there in order to find: **R1,R2,C,L**

[image]

Comment: Some user asked about a similar circuit about 4 years ago but couldn't find a solid answer :(

Comment: What if you set R1=R2, Ir1=Ir2 and jwfL = 1/jwfC?

Comment: For \$V_1\$ = 0, means \$V_L\$ and \$V_{R_2}\$ must be equal (35V) and \$V_{R_1}\$ and \$V_C\$  must be equal.

Comment: If power factor is 1 then the equivalent impedance seen by \$U_G\$ is pure resistance i.e. has no \$j\omega\$ term. Write the equivalent impedance i.e. parallel of of \$R_1+j\omega L\$ and \$R_2-j/\omega C\$ in \$Z_e=R_x+j\omega X\$ form and equalise the imaginary term to 0 to find the relationship between \$L\$ and \$C\$, and \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$. Alternatively, you can go through the total current: it's flowing through the two branches and is 10A in  total. Since the PF is 1, current and voltage should be in-phase. In other words, the capacitive and inductive reactance cancel each other.

Comment: I think you accepted a wrong answer.

Comment: @PStechPaul you are right, I accepted it wrongly. However, I was able to do the university task using your answer, so thank you, I really appreciated!

Comment: I had wrongly assumed the frequency was 190 Hz, and not 190 radians/sec, or 30.25 Hz. I hope you didn't get dinged for the wrong answer.

Comment: There is another post where @Andy aka give another way of solving. Same circuit, 4 years ago. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/363689/basic-ac-circuit-analysis-w-wattmeter/640807#640807

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To confirm answer @JanEerland and another mode of demonstration.
As there are 2 networks in parallel, the use of "admittance" is more interesting.
-> so the use of [gsL and gsC] in place of [zsL and zsC].

NB: in simulation,values used are peak. So current & voltage answers are peak.
If there were RMS, one would read "RMS" (all multiplied by sqrt(2)).

[image]

Maple sheet.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, this proves my point ;). +1

Comment: Your simulation shows a period of about 33 ms which is about 30.2 Hz. I had assumed a frequency of 190 Hz. But I see it is radians per second.

Comment: No worries. Nobody is perfect. I did also an error on my first sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simulation that has the correct values (for 190 Hz), but my method may be a bit strange. (I have provided a corrected method and answer in my edits).

[image: Simulation - 190 Hz]

First, I assumed that equal current would flow in each leg, and with 10 amps from the source, I used 5 amps for each leg. Then I used the Pythagorean theorem to solve for V(R1) and V(C1) using 35 V for V(L1) and V(C1), with applied 90 V. This results in 83 V for each. Thus R1 = 83/5 = 16.6 and X(C1) = 16.6. For f = 190 Hz, L1 = 5.8 mH and C1 = 50.5 uF. R2 = 35/5 = 7 ohms.

With those values, the simulation shows the correct voltages, but the total current is 7.07 A. This is 10 / sqrt(2), so I multiplied the values for C1 and R2 by this factor, and divided the values for R1 and L1 by this factor.

I don't know why this is the case. It indicates a phase angle of 45 degrees with resistive current of 5 A and reactive current of 5 A in each leg. But the phase angle should be atan( 16.6/7 ) = 67.1 degrees for the capacitive leg, and atan( 7/16.6 ) = 22.9 degrees for the inductive leg. And using the resistive and reactive voltages of 83 V and 35 V also shows atan ( 83/35 ) = 67.1 degrees and 22.9 degrees.

There must be some mistake in my assumptions, but I'm not seeing it. I use the simulator for most such analysis, and my vector math is very rusty, and never was my strong point.

(edit) I see that the phase angle between capacitive and inductive current is 67.1 + 22.9 = 90 degrees, so the total reactive current is at 45 degrees, probably explaining the 0.707 factor.

===============================edit=============================

I mistakenly assumed the frequency to be 190 Hz, rather than 190 radians/s (30.25 Hz), so the above is incorrect. However, it is interesting that my assumption of equal current in the inductive and capacitive legs produced a valid answer. So here is my simulation using 30.25 Hz, and the component values as computed by @Antonio51.

[image: Simulation for 30.25 Hz]

========================== edit 2 =============================

Here is a visual representation of the vectors involved in the calculation of the component values. I think it is a bit simpler and more intuitive than the more math intensive answers provided.

[image: Vector representation]

Comment: I think that you made a mistake, but I don't know where exactly.

Comment: My mistake was assuming the frequency was 190 Hz, rather than radians/s.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fttmmo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The real input power is given by:

$$\text{P}_\text{i}:=\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}\text{I}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}\cos\left(\varphi_\text{i}\right)\tag1$$

Now, we know that:

- $$\text{I}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}=\frac{\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}}{\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right|}\tag2$$
- $$\varphi_\text{i}=\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)\tag3$$
  Where \$\arg\left(\cdot\right)\$ is the principal value of the complex argument.
- $$\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}=\left(\text{R}_1+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)\space\text{||}\space\left(\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\right)=\frac{\left(\text{R}_1+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)\left(\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\right)}{\text{R}_1+\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}\tag4$$
  Where \$\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta}\$.

Knowing that the power factor is equal to one, we can conclude that:

$$\cos\left(\varphi_\text{i}\right)=1\space\Longrightarrow\space\varphi_\text{i}=\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\Im\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)=0\tag5$$

Working this out leaves you with:

$$\text{L}-\text{CR}_1^2+\text{CL}\omega^2\left(\text{CR}_2^2-\text{L}\right)=0\tag6$$

Using \$(1)\$, \$(2)\$ and \$(5)\$ we can see that:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{P}_\text{i}&=\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}\cdot\underbrace{\cos\left(\varphi_\text{i}\right)}_{=\space1}\\
\\
&=\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}\cdot\frac{\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}}{\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right|}\\
\\
&=\frac{\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}^2}{\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right|}\\
\\
&=\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}^2\cdot\left|\frac{\text{R}_1+\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}{\left(\text{R}_1+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)\left(\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\right)}\right|\\
\\
&=\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}^2\cdot\frac{\left|\text{R}_1+\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\right|}{\left|\text{R}_1+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right|\cdot\left|\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\right|}\\
\\
&=\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}^2\cdot\frac{\sqrt{\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)^2+\left(\omega\text{L}-\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\right)^2}}{\sqrt{\text{R}_1^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}\cdot\sqrt{\text{R}_2^2+\left(-\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\right)^2}}\\
\\
&=\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}^2\cdot\frac{\sqrt{\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)^2+\left(\omega\text{L}-\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\right)^2}}{\sqrt{\text{R}_1^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}\cdot\sqrt{\text{R}_2^2+\left(\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\right)^2}}
\end{split}\tag7
\end{equation}

The RMS-voltage over \$\text{R}_2\$ is given by:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{V}_{\text{R}_2\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\text{R}_2\cdot\left|\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{R}_2}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\text{R}_2\cdot\left|\frac{\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{i}}}{\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{R}_2}}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\text{R}_2\cdot\frac{\left|\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{i}}\right|}{\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{R}_2}\right|}\\
\\
&=\underbrace{\frac{\left|\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{i}}\right|}{\sqrt{2}}}_{:=\space\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}}\cdot\text{R}_2\cdot\frac{1}{\left|\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{R}_2\right|}\\
\\
&=\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}\cdot\text{R}_2\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{R}_2^2+\left(-\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\right)^2}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}\text{R}_2}{\sqrt{\text{R}_2^2+\left(-\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\right)^2}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}\text{R}_2}{\sqrt{\text{R}_2^2+\left(\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\right)^2}}
\end{split}\tag8
\end{equation}

In oder to satisfy that fact that the voltage between the coil and the second resistor is equal to zero we need to set the amplitude and argument of those voltages equal to eachother. So, let's first find the amplitude of the voltage across the coil:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{V}_{\text{L}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left|\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right|\cdot\left|\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{L}}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left|\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right|\cdot\left|\frac{\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{i}}}{\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{R}_1+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left|\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right|\cdot\frac{\left|\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{i}}\right|}{\left|\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{R}_1+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}\right|}\\
\\
&=\underbrace{\frac{\left|\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{i}}\right|}{\sqrt{2}}}_{:=\space\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}}\cdot\left|\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right|\cdot\frac{1}{\left|\text{R}_1+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right|}\\
\\
&=\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}\cdot\omega\text{L}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{R}_1^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}\omega\text{L}}{\sqrt{\text{R}_1^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}}
\end{split}\tag9
\end{equation}

So, we get the condition that \$(8)\$ must equal \$(9)\$:

$$\frac{\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}\text{R}_2}{\sqrt{\text{R}_2^2+\left(\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\right)^2}}=\frac{\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space\text{rms}}\omega\text{L}}{\sqrt{\text{R}_1^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\frac{\text{R}_2^2}{\text{R}_2^2+\left(\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\right)^2}=\frac{\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}{\text{R}_1^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}\tag{10}$$

And for the arguments we get:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{L}}\right)&=\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{R}_2}\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\\
\\
\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{L}}\cdot\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)&=\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{R}_2}\cdot\text{R}_2\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\\
\\
\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{L}}\right)+\arg\left(\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)&=\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{R}_2}\right)+\arg\left(\text{R}_2\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\\
\\
\arg\left(\frac{\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{i}}}{\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{R}_1+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}&=\arg\left(\frac{\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{i}}}{\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{R}_2}}\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\\
\\
\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)-\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{R}_1+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}&=\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)-\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{R}_2}\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\\
\\
\frac{\pi}{2}-\arg\left(\text{R}_1+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)&=-\arg\left(\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{R}_2\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\\
\\
\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}_1}\right)-\frac{\pi}{2}&=\frac{3\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\frac{\text{R}_2}{\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}}\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\\
\\
\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}_1}\right)-\frac{\pi}{2}&=\frac{3\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\omega\text{C}\text{R}_2\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\\
\\
\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}_1}\right)-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi&=\frac{3\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\omega\text{C}\text{R}_2\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\\
\\
\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}_1}\right)+\frac{3\pi}{2}&=\frac{3\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\omega\text{C}\text{R}_2\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\\
\\
\arctan\left(\frac{\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}_1}\right)&=\arctan\left(\omega\text{C}\text{R}_2\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\\
\\
\frac{\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}_1}&=\omega\text{C}\text{R}_2\space\Longleftrightarrow\\
\\
\frac{\text{L}}{\text{R}_1}&=\text{C}\text{R}_2
\end{split}\tag{11}
\end{equation}

> Now, I wrote some Mathematica-code to solve this question using the equations from above and found:
>
> $$\text{C}=\frac{7}{8550 \sqrt{11}}\approx0.000246\space\text{F},\space\text{L}=\frac{63}{950 \sqrt{11}}\approx0.0199\space\text{H},\space\text{R}_1=9\space\Omega,\space\text{R}_2=9\space\Omega$$

---

The Mathematica-code I used is:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
P = 900;
Virms = 90;
VR2irms = 35;
\[Omega] = 190;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{L - c*R1^2 + c*L*\[Omega]^2*(c*R2^2 - L) == 0, 
   P == Virms^2*(Sqrt[(R1 + 
            R2)^2 + (\[Omega]*L - (1/(\[Omega]*c)))^2]/(Sqrt[
          R1^2 + (\[Omega]*L)^2]*Sqrt[R2^2 + (1/(\[Omega]*c))^2])), 
   VR2irms == (Virms*R2)/
     Sqrt[R2^2 + (1/(\[Omega]*c))^2], (R2^2)/(R2^2 + (1/(\[Omega]*
            c))^2) == (\[Omega]*L)^2/(R1^2 + (\[Omega]*L)^2), 
   L/R1 == c*R2, c > 0 && L > 0 && R1 > 0 && R2 > 0}, {c, L, R1, R2}]]

Out[1]={{c -> 7/(8550 Sqrt[11]), L -> 63/(950 Sqrt[11]), R1 -> 9, R2 -> 9}}

In[2]:=N[%1]

Out[2]={{c -> 0.000246851, L -> 0.019995, R1 -> 9., R2 -> 9.}}
```

Comment: Can the one who devoted my answer explain why ....! Thanks.

Comment: Not my downvote, but your values are wrong. See my answer above, which is proven by simulation.

Comment: @PStechPaul No, my values are not wrong. I did the same simulation with my values and got the correct result.

Comment: @JanEerland  Good work. Finally, I retrieve my little error. I confirm the result and add later in answer with Maple sheet. My demonstration is shorter.

Comment: Sorry, your values are correct, and I will upvote to counter the downvote, although that was not done by me.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my comment, in order to make the power factor 1, the equivalent impedance of the network should be pure resistive. Now let \$\mathrm{R_X}\$ be the equivalent resistance of the network:

$$
\mathrm{
(R_1 + Z_L) \ || \ (R_2 + Z_C) = R_X \\
=\frac{(R_1+sL)(R_2+1/sC)}{R_1+R_2+sL+1/sC} \\
=\frac{sR_1R_2+R_1+s^2R_2LC+sL}{sC(R_1+R_2)+s^2LC+1}=R_X \\
\Rightarrow sR_1R_2C+s^2R_2LC+sL+R1=sR_XC(R_1+R_2)+s^2R_XLC+R_X \\
\Rightarrow s^2(R_2LC)+s(R_1R_2C+L)+R_1=s^2(R_XLC)+sR_XC(R_1+R_2)+R_X
}
$$

As can be seen from above, \$\mathrm{s}\$ and \$\mathrm{s^2}\$ have to have equal factors on both sides. So,

1. \$\mathrm{R_1=R_2=R_X}\$ - The resistances are equal to each other, and to the equivalent resistance.
2. \$\mathrm{R_X^2=R_1^2=R_2^2=L/C}\$ - The relationship between the reactive components.

---

Input voltage is 90V, total current is 10A, so the equivalent resistance is \$\mathrm{R_X=9\Omega}\$ which brings \$\mathrm{R_1=R_2=9\Omega}\$.

---

Since \$\mathrm{V_1=0}\$, the RMS voltage across L and \$\mathrm{R_2}\$ are equal. Let \$\mathrm{i_1}\$ and \$\mathrm{i_2}\$ be the currents flowing through the 1st and 2nd branches, respectively. So,

$$
\mathrm{10\ A = \sqrt{i_1^2+i_2^2}}
$$

and

$$
\mathrm{V_L=i_1 \ X_L = 35V}
$$

and

$$
\mathrm{V_G^2=(i_1 \ R_1)^2+V_L^2 \\ 
\Rightarrow i_1 \ R_1 = 25\sqrt{11} \\ 
\Rightarrow i_1=9.213 \ A}
$$

So,

$$
\mathrm{35V = \omega L \ i_1 \\
L\approx 20\ mH}
$$

---

From the second result above,  the relationship between the resistances and the reactive components:

$$
\mathrm{\frac{L}{C}=R_1^2 \\ 
\Rightarrow C = 247 \ \mu F}
$$

---

Let's check and verify:

$$
\mathrm{V_C=i_2\ X_C}
$$

and

$$
\mathrm{90^2=35^2+V_C^2 \\
\Rightarrow V_C=25\sqrt{11} \\ 
\Rightarrow i_2=V_C/X_C=\frac{25\sqrt{11}}{1/\omega C}=3.89\ A}
$$

So, total current is

$$
\mathrm{i=\sqrt{i_1^2+i_2^2}=\sqrt{9.213^2+3.89^2} \approx 10\ A}
$$

Verified!

---

**CONCLUSION**

$$
\mathrm{R_1=R_2=9\Omega}
$$

$$
\mathrm{C= 247 \ \mu F}
$$

$$
\mathrm{L= 20 \ mH}
$$